# Find subexpression to minimize leafcount after replacment with temporary variable

Tags: pattern-matching

Given an expression `expr`, is there an automated way to find a subexpression `subexpr` such that replacing `subexpr` with a temporary variable `v` minimizes `LeafCount[expr//.subexpr->v]+LeafCount[subexpr]` over all possible `subexpr`?

To provide a concrete example to work with, here is a cleaned up small fragment of an expression that someone asked an unrelated question about recently:

```
(1/Sqrt[2](Sqrt[((Sqrt[((-x3 - (1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) + x3 Tan[a] - x3 (-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]) - Tan[b])/(-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]))^2 + (-1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) - x3 Tan[a] + Tan[b])^2)] + Sqrt[((-x3 - Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a])/(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])))^2 + (-1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) - x3 Tan[a] -
(Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) Tan[b])/(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])))^2)] + Sqrt[((-(Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]))/(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])) + (1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) + x3 Tan[a] - x3 (-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]) - Tan[b])/(-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]))^2 + (-Tan[b] -
(Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) Tan[b])/(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])))^2)])(-Sqrt[((-x3 - (1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) + x3 Tan[a] - x3 (-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]) - Tan[b])/(-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]))^2 + (-1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) - x3 Tan[a] +
Tan[b])^2)] + 1/2 (Sqrt[((-x3 - (1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) + x3 Tan[a] - x3 (- m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a])-Tan[b])/(-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]))^2 + (-1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) -x3 Tan[a] + Tan[b])^2)] + Sqrt[((-x3 - (Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]))/
(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])))^2 + (-1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) - x3 Tan[a] -(Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) Tan[b])/(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])))^2)] +Sqrt[((-(Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]))/(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])) +(1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) + x3 Tan[a] - x3 (-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) +
Tan[a])-Tan[b])/(-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]))^2 + (-Tan[b] -(Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) Tan[b])/(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])))^2)])))]))
```

The original problem had a LeafCount of almost 6000. Fumbling with manual substitutions I was finally able to make the structure clear and that happened to enable `Simplify` to reduce the total LeafCount to about 250 in a few seconds.

Is there a simple method of automating this? It would be even better if it could recognize and handle `-subexpr` and `1/subexpr` as containing `subexpr`, but that may be too much to ask.

Note: I'm trying to actually see the result, not just have Mathematica do subexpression sharing behind the scenes where I cannot see what happened.

Comment: If your `subexpression == expression` the count comes down to 1. So perhaps other restrictions are in place ... and ought to be specified

Comment: @belisarius Well, you could say that the leafcount to minimize is the leafcount of the expression along with any expression needed to define the used subexpressions, then the result makes slightly more sense.

Answer (score 21):

The compiler does a pretty good job of finding and eliminating common subexpressions.  We can leverage that functionality.

Starting from the provided expression...

```
$expr = (1/Sqrt[2](Sqrt[((Sqrt[((-x3 - (1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) + x3 Tan[a] - x3 (-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]) - Tan[b])/(-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]))^2 + (-1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) - x3 Tan[a] + Tan[b])^2)] + Sqrt[((-x3 - Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a])/(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])))^2 + (-1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) - x3 Tan[a] - (Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) Tan[b])/(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])))^2)] + Sqrt[((-(Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]))/(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])) + (1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) + x3 Tan[a] - x3 (-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]) - Tan[b])/(-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]))^2 + (-Tan[b] - (Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) Tan[b])/(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])))^2)])(-Sqrt[((-x3 - (1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) + x3 Tan[a] - x3 (-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]) - Tan[b])/(-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]))^2 + (-1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) - x3 Tan[a] + Tan[b])^2)] + 1/2 (Sqrt[((-x3 - (1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) + x3 Tan[a] - x3 (- m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a])-Tan[b])/(-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]))^2 + (-1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) -x3 Tan[a] + Tan[b])^2)] + Sqrt[((-x3 - (Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]))/ (2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])))^2 + (-1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) - x3 Tan[a] -(Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) Tan[b])/(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])))^2)] +Sqrt[((-(Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]))/(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])) +(1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) + x3 Tan[a] - x3 (-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a])-Tan[b])/(-m Sec[a]/(x2-x3) + Tan[a]))^2 + (-Tan[b] -(Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]) Tan[b])/(2 (Tan[a]-Tan[b])))^2)])))]));
```

We extract the variable names:

```
$variables = Cases[$expr, _Symbol, Infinity] // Union

(* {a, b, h, m, x2, x3} *)
```

Now we compile the expression.  The result is an object which can be destructured.  We are interested in the component which represents the compiled `Function` expression:

```
$function =
  Cases[
Compile[##]&[$variables, $expr]
  , x_Function :> x
  ] // First

(*
Function[{a,b,h,m,x2,x3},
  Block[{Compile`$398,Compile`$406,[...snip...],Compile`$441},
    Compile`$398=-3;
Compile`$406=Cos[a];
    Compile`$403=Tan[a];
Compile`$399=x2+Compile`$398;
    [...snip...]
    Compile`$441=Compile`$423+Compile`$433+Compile`$440;
    Sqrt[Compile`$441 (-Compile`$423+Compile`$441/2)]/Sqrt[2]]]
*)
```

In this result, we can see that the compiler has found all of the common subexpressions and assigned them to variables with generated names.

If the output is intended for machine consumption, we are done.  All of the symbols have been safely localized.  But as humans, we might find all of the generated symbol names distracting.  We can apply a few more transformations in the interest of readability.

We will change all of the variables of the form `` Compile`$nnn `` to `p[n]`, where `p` is carefully chosen as a symbol that does not appear in the original expression:

```
FreeQ[$expr, p]

(* True *)
```

The following transformations do the trick:

```
$cse =
  Cases[$function, s_Symbol /; "Compile`" === Context[s], Infinity] //
  DeleteDuplicates //
  MapIndexed[#1 -> p@@#2 &, #]& //
  $function /.
    # /.
    HoldPattern[Function[_, Block[_, b_]]] :> Hold@\[FormalM][{p}, b] /.
    \[FormalM] -> Module &

(*
Hold[Module[{p},
  p[1] = -x3;p[2] = Cos[a]; p[3] = Tan[a]; 
  p[4] = x2 + p[1]; p[5] = 1/p[4]; p[6] = Sec[a]; p[7] = -m p[5] p[6];
  [...snip...]
  p[44] = p[30] + p[36] + p[43];
  Sqrt[p[44] (-p[30] + p[44]/2)]/Sqrt[2]]]
*)
```

The final expression expands to the original expression when evaluated:

```
$expr === ReleaseHold[$cse]

(* True *)
```

If desired, another transformation will give us a base expression and replacement rules:

```
$rep =
  $cse /. Hold[Module[_, CompoundExpression[s___, f_]]] :> Hold[f /. {s}] /. Set -> Rule

(*
Hold[Sqrt[p[44](-p[30]+p[44]/2)]/Sqrt[2] /. {p[1]->-x3, p[2]->Cos[a], [...snip...]}]
*)
```

Inspection of this result reveals that the compiler sometimes introduces temporary variables even for expressions that are only used once.  Such variables appear exactly twice in the expression -- once to define it and once for its use:

```
$unnecessary = Cases[Cases[$rep, p[_], Infinity] // Tally, {_, 2}][[All, 1]]

(*
{p[4],p[5],p[6],p[7],p[9],p[15],p[19],p[20],p[21],p[24],p[25],p[26],p[27],p[28],
 p[29],p[31],p[32],p[33],p[34],p[35],p[36],p[37],p[38],p[39],p[40],p[41],p[42],p[43]}
*)
```

We can further simplify the compiler's expression by removing these unnecessary variables:

```
$cse2 =
  Verbatim[Rule][Alternatives @@ $unnecessary, _] //
  DeleteCases[$rep, #, Infinity] //. Cases[$rep, #, Infinity] &
```

[image: simplified expression]

Once again, this expression is equivalent to the original when evaluated:

```
ReleaseHold[$cse2] === $expr

(* True *)
```

**Just For Fun**

Sometimes a layered graph plot can come in handy when trying to visualize the structure of complex expressions:

```
edge[x:_[___]] := (Scan[If[!AtomQ[#], Sow[x -> #]]& , x]; x)
edge[x_] := x
Reap[edge //@ $expr][[2, 1]] // DeleteDuplicates //
LayeredGraphPlot[#, Top, DirectedEdges -> False]&
```

[image: layered graph plot]

The expression at each node is revealed as a tooltip when the mouse hovers over a vertex.

Comment: you could also use ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression[$expr]``

Comment: +2 Beachcombing the compiled code is a great idea!

Comment: Great idea and answer!

Comment: Is there a limit to how large an expression that Mathematica will do common subexpression elimination on?

I have an expression with LeafCount of 98701 with 6 variables and 
`{List, Log, Plus, Power, Times} ` as heads  (from 
`Cases[$expr, x_[__] -> x, {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True] // Union`   )

Comment: @ÅsmundHj Sorry, but I have no knowledge concerning the upper limits of this machinery.

Comment: I have spent a few days to solve this kind of problem by procedural programming. You can solve it with a few lines. Amazing.

Comment: I tested this solution on my expression. It occured that one more step is required:  `$cse3 = $cse2 /. ReplaceAll -> ReplaceRepeated`.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov I don't understand... the expression for `$cse2` already uses `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`).  Where should I insert another?

Comment: I mean that code assigned to `@cse2` contains `/.` rather than `//`. In my case this left unsubstituted some coefficients. So that `$expr === ReleaseHold[$cse2]` is evaluated to `False`.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov We must be looking at different things... I see `//.` in `$cse2`, not `/.`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that we assign your test expression to a variable `expr`, and using my [common subexpression eliminator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2878/problem-with-compile-function/2885#2885) gives immediately without any tweaking:

```
res = csub[Hold[Evaluate[expr]], {}, 10]

(*

 Hold[
   Let[{
      $3:=-((m Sec[a])/(x2-x3))+Tan[a],
      $4:=1/2 Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a])+x3 Tan[a]-x3 $3-Tan[b],
      $5:=-(1/2) Cos[a] (m-h Cos[a]),
      $6:=(Tan[b] $5)/(Tan[a]-Tan[b]),
      $7:=$5/(Tan[a]-Tan[b]),
      $8:=(-x3-$4/$3)^2+($5-x3 Tan[a]+Tan[b])^2,
      $9:=Sqrt[$8]+Sqrt[(-x3+$7)^2+($5-x3 Tan[a]+$6)^2]+
           Sqrt[($7+$4/$3)^2+(-Tan[b]+$6)^2]
     },
     Hold[Sqrt[$9 (-Sqrt[$8]+$9/2)]/Sqrt[2]]
   ]
 ]

*)
```

Please see the mentioned post for the definitions of `csub` and `Let`. The `LeafCount` of this is 195, and that includes 2 extra `Hold`-s and one `Let`, all of which are strictly not parts of the expression. Note that calling

```
ReleaseHold@ReleaseHold@res
```

will bring you back to your expression.

Comment: Hi Leonid! Just out of laziness ... How do I invoke it to treat something like `expr = (Sin[(x + y + z)]/(x + y + z))^(x + y + z)`?

Comment: Hi @belisarius! You will have to modify code for `csub` a bit, and tweak the `limitCount` parameter. In the code for `csub`, I put a restriction `Depth[Unevaluated[x]] > 2`. Change this to `Depth[Unevaluated[x]] > 1`, and set `limitCount` to 2 (say):  `csub[Hold[Evaluate[expr]], {}, 2]`. I get then: `Hold[Let[{$25 := x + y + z}, Hold[(Sin[$25]/$25)^$25]]]`. I should probably make a minimal depth as a parameter. I could also add a `LeafCount` minimizer which would automatically try different values for parameters and optimize minimal depth  and `limitCount`.

Comment: Ok. Got it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have such things fully automated, but as for tips to help you identify subexpressions, I think this is helpfull:

```
 PatternTable[
     expression_] := {(#[[1]] - 1) (#[[2]] - 1), #[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]} & /@
      ({Count[exp, #, \[Infinity]], LeafCount[#], #} & /@ 
       Cases[exp, _, \[Infinity]] // Union) // Sort // Reverse
```

I know it's messy, but it's just suggestive. 
It returns a list of lists containing

```
 {score number(to be explained), number of appearances, leafcount, and sub-expression}
```

Then you can look through it and see which expressions seem worth it for you to define separately. The score number is just an estimate of how much you can reduce the leaf count by making the replacement, it goes by the logic, that if you have n appearances of a subexpression with l leafs, then you can at most replace n-1, since you still need it once in your definition, and you still leave 1 leaf everywhere you replace it, so the score is (n-1)(l-1). It serves nicely to sort the expressions into a suggestive order.

You can then skim through the entire list, or sort it depeding on what you deam suitable criteria for a replacement being worth it, for example for your given expression.

```
((replacements = 
  Cases[PatternTable[expression], 
 {score_ /; score > 20, count_ /; count > 3, leaf_ /; leaf > 5, exp_}
 ])) // Column
```

> ```
>  {
>  {156, 5, 40, 1/2 Cos[a] (m - h Cos[a]) + x3 Tan[a] -  x3 (-((m Sec[a])/(x2 - x3)) +Tan[a]) - Tan[b]},
>  {126, 10, 15, -((m Sec[a])/(x2 - x3)) + Tan[a]},
>  {102, 18, 7, m - h Cos[a]},
>  {99, 10, 12, -((m Sec[a])/(x2 - x3))},
>  {69, 4, 24, -((Cos[a] (m - h Cos[a]) Tan[b])/(2 (Tan[a] - Tan[b])))}},
>  {68, 5, 18, -x3 (-((m Sec[a])/(x2 - x3)) + Tan[a])},
>  .... + 7 more
>  }
> ```

If you take these and substitute into the expression it ends up reducing the leafcount, but not alot if you take into acount the leafcount needed to define the subesxpressions.

```
 subexpressions = Rule @@@ ({replacements[[1 ;;, -1]], 
    shortexp /@ Range[Length[replacements]]}\[Transpose])

 subexpressions // LeafCount
 exp /. subexpressions // LeafCount
```

> ```
> 244
> 200
> ```

So down from 693 to 444, but it may help as an aide in further simplifications.

Comment: Nice, but of course you can't overcome with this Mma's particular idiosyncrasy for representing expressions. Try `e = (Sin[(x + y + z)]/(x + y + z))^(x + y + z)`

Comment: @belisarius I'm not sure what you mean, with that particular expression the only replacement with a positive score is x+y+z, which seems a reasonable substitution.

Comment: Yes, but I am not getting it from your code above. Perhaps my fault. Rechecking

Comment: You won't get it from using that definition of replacements, no. But the sorting is as I stated just a way to reduce the number of replacements, in your case the obvious thing would be to examine the entire list since it's just around 10 entries and notice that all but one are useless.