# A kind of function optimization problem

Tags: function-construction, replacement, map

I have the following problem.

Out of a calculation I got the four functions shown at the end of the post.
These functions depends on many variables, qk, pk etc (all of them are actually scalar products but that is irrelevant for the question I would like to pose.)

The problem I would like to solve with Mathematica is the following: find a way to write the four functions with a minimal numbers of composite variables that maximally repeat over them. The need for this is that these functions will be integrated over in a numerical code, and replacing repeated symbols with composite ones, saves an enormous amount of runtime.

I make some examples to be clear. The combination r12*r32 appears 24 times so one replaces it with r12*r32 -> r12r32 (and saves 24 operations); next
the denominator of the functions is also common; the replacement d -> 2*k2*r12r32 saves four more operations.

With a little patience and a lot of find/replace one can do this to a certain extent; but what I would like to have is a general algorithm (as I will need to apply this also in the next steps of my calculations with different functions) that can give me the optimal mapping, i.e., provides a replacement rule that minimizes the number of operations done in the functions with the minimal number of new composite variables definitions.

**Updated**: Thanks to the comments of Bill and Yves below I was pointed to similar questions, and in particular to the `OptimizeExpression` function. However when I apply this function to say `f1` above, the mapping returned is empty (there are no `Compile$` definitions). If I `Expand` the function I obtain four `Compile$` corresponding to `1/p2, 1/k2, 1/r12` and `1/r32`, which fail short to achieve what I need as there are many more combinations (e.g., `kr1 wr3`) that are just not identified.

Any idea why?

Thanks,
D

```
f1 = 3/(2 k2 p2 r12 r32) (k2 (kr1 (-pq r32 wr1 + pr1 qw r32 - 
       2 pr3 qr1 wr3 - 2 pr3 qr3 wr1 + 2 pr3 qw r1r3 + 
       pw qr1 r32) + 
    kr3 (pq r12 wr3 + 2 pr1 qr1 wr3 + 2 pr3 qr1 wr1 - pr3 qw r12 -
        pw (2 qr1 r1r3 + qr3 r12)) - 2 pk qr1 r32 wr1 - 
    2 pk qw r12 r32 - pq r12 r1r3 wr3 - 2 pq r12 r32 wr1 + 
    2 pq r12 r32 wr3 + pq r1r3 r32 wr1 - 2 pr1 qr1 r32 wk + 
    2 pr1 qr3 r12 wr3 - 2 pr1 qr3 r32 wr1 + pr1 qw r1r3 r32 + 
    2 pr3 qk r12 wr3 + 2 pr3 qr1 r12 wr3 - 2 pr3 qr1 r32 wr1 + 
    2 pr3 qr3 r12 wk + pr3 qw r12 r1r3 - 2 pr3 qw r12 r32 + 
    2 pw qk r12 r32 + 2 pw qr1 r12 r32 - pw qr1 r1r3 r32 - 
    pw qr3 r12 r1r3) + 
 kr3 (2 kr1 pq r12 wr3 - 2 kr1 pq r32 wr1 + 2 pk qr1 r32 wr1 - 
    pk qw r12 r32 - pq r12 r32 wk + 2 pr1 qk r32 wr1 + 
    pw qk r12 (r32 - 2 r1r3)) - 2 kr1 pk qr3 r12 wr3 - 
 kr1 pk qw r12 r32 + 2 kr1 pk qw r1r3 r32 + kr1 pq r12 r32 wk - 
 2 kr1 pr3 qk r12 wr3 + kr1 pw qk r12 r32 + 
 2 pk qk r12 r1r3 wr3 - 2 pk qk r12 r32 wr1 + 
 2 pk qk r12 r32 wr3 - 2 pk qk r1r3 r32 wr1 - 
 2 pk qr1 r1r3 r32 wk + 2 pk qr3 r12 r32 wk - 
 2 pr1 qk r12 r32 wk + 2 pr3 qk r12 r1r3 wk);

f2 = 3/(2 k2 p2 r12 r32) (k2 (kr1 pr1 r32 + 2 kr1 pr3 r1r3 + 
    kr3 pr3 r12 - 4 pk r12 r32 + pr1 r1r3 r32 + 3 pr3 r12 r1r3 - 
    4 pr3 r12 r32) + pk r32 (-3 kr1 r12 + 2 kr1 r1r3 + kr3 r12));

f3 = -3/(2 k2 r12 r32) (k2 (kr1 qr1 r32 + 2 kr3 qr1 r1r3 + 
        kr3 qr3 r12 - 4 qk r12 r32 - 4 qr1 r12 r32 + 3 qr1 r1r3 r32 + 
        qr3 r12 r1r3) + qk r12 (kr1 r32 + 2 kr3 r1r3 - 3 kr3 r32));

f4 = 3/(2 k2 r12 r32) (kr1 (-3 k2 r32 wr1 + 2 kr3 r12 wr3 - 
        2 kr3 r32 wr1 + r12 r32 wk) + kr3 r12 (3 k2 wr3 - r32 wk) + 
     k2 (r12 (r1r3 wr3 - 4 r32 wr1 + 4 r32 wr3) - r1r3 r32 wr1));
```

Comment: This https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/find-subexpression-to-minimize-leafcount-after-replacment-with-temporary-variabl    and the other resources that links to might be helpful.

Comment: @bill @YvesKlett Thank you for the pointers. Indeed the problem is of the same kind to what appears there (the only, maybe trivial, difference being that we have here a system of functions rather than a single function). However if I apply `ExperimentalOptimizeExpression[$expr]` with `$expr` being f1, the mapping returned is empty (there are no `Compile$` definition). If I `Expand` the function I obtain four `Compile$` corresponding to `1/p2, 1/k2, 1/r12` and `1/r32`, which fail short to achieve what I need as there are many more combinations (e.g., kr1 wr3) that are just not identified.

Comment: You could update your question to reflect the shortcomings of the linked posts. The call in your last comment is not correct (missing back tick)  - is that intentional?

Comment: I have updated my original question. The back tick is indeed missing (I did not manage to make it print, sorry about that).

Comment: Did you try the other solutions to the linked question(s)? Your question seems to be a duplicate topic-wise at the moment, but perhaps you can differentiate is suitably to stand alone...

Comment: I tried everything. I see it is no different question, but everything suggested in the other questions is not working here (for unfathomable reasons, as far as I am concerned).

Comment: Hi, there used to be a C/Fortran generator package for Mathematica that would output optimised expressions but it does not seem to be around anymore. Could Haggies help ?https://sourceforge.net/projects/haggies/

Comment: @TradDog Thank you for the suggestion. I will have a look as Mathematica is not working for the particular functions I have posted.