# Making a equation smaller and more readable by using another variable

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, resolve

I am deriving an expression and the output of it is a very long mathematical expression. I want to minimize the equation by substituting some other variables. For example:

[image]
This is just an example equation, is it possible for mathematica to automatically do this?

Comment: Have a look at `Replace` and `ReplaceAll`. An example using the latter would be `output /. {Sin[x + y] -> a, Cos[x + y] -> b}`.

Comment: Is it possible for Mathematica to provide this A and B in the solution?

Comment: This question has already been asked and aswered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8806/9469).