# Can I speed up ParametricNDSolve by converting ODE to DAE?

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, special-functions

I use `ParametricNDSolve` to find a solution to a very cumbersome ODE:

```
pf2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode2$[z, k, \[Beta], 
     Rm, {q, Km}, \[CapitalLambda]] == 0, \[Phi][0] == 
    1, \[Phi]'[0] == 0}, {\[Phi]'[zR$], \[Phi][zR$]}, {z, 
   0, (1 + 10^-7) zR$}
  , {{\[Beta], 0, 1}, {\[CapitalLambda], 1, 1000}}
  , Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}
  ]
```

Equation `ode2$[z, k, \[Beta], Rm, {q, Km}, \[CapitalLambda]]` is too big to show here. The only significant thing is that the parameters `Rm`, `q`, `Km` are given by numbers in some `Do` loop, and the parameters `\[CapitalLambda]`, `\[Beta]` are free. The parametric function `pf2[\[Beta], \[CapitalLambda]]` returned by `ParametricNDSolveValue` is then used to construct another equation:

```
eqn2[\[Beta]_?NumericQ, \[CapitalLambda]_?NumericQ] = 
 pf2[\[Beta], \[CapitalLambda]] . {1, -BC1$[k, \[Beta], 
     Rm, {q, Km}, \[CapitalLambda]]}
```

I find the root of the equation `eqn2[\[Beta], \[CapitalLambda]] ==0` given the value `\[CapitalLambda]`. All of this works great, but in the particular case of `k==4` the calculations take about 300 times longer than with other values of `k`.

The reason is probably that for `k==4` the `ode2` equation contains 73 calls to the Appell hypergeometric function `AppellF1`. They occur both in the numerator and denominator of the coefficients of the equation. However, out of these 73 functions, only 7 have a different set of arguments. So I'm wondering how to make it so that I can first calculate these 7 functions and then re-use the calculated values in the coefficients of the equation. Here's how I came up with the equation modification:

```
"original equation ODE of 2nd order, too long to show "
ode[z, 4, p, R, \[CapitalLambda]];
"compose list of all AppellF1 functions"
n = 1;
list = {};
ode[z, 4, p, 
   R, \[CapitalLambda]] //. {AppellF1[a_, b1_, b2_, c_, x_, 
     y_] :> {AppendTo[list, AppellF1[a, b1, b2, c, x, y]];}};
"number of such functions"
list // Length
"list of unique functions and number of its occurences"
Tally[list]
list = Sort@DeleteDuplicates[list];
% // Length
"compose Rule to make substitutions in ODE"
n = 1;
rule4 = (# -> F[4, n++]) & /@ list
"compose algebraic equations for substituted AppellF1 functions"
n = 1;
setOde[z_, 4, p_, R_] = 
 Table[F[4, n], {n, Length[list]}] == list // Thread
"modifield equation ODE of 2nd order, too long to show "
ode[z, 4, p, R, \[CapitalLambda]] /. rule4;
```

This code gives this result:

```
"original equation ODE of 2nd order, too long to show "

"compose list of all AppellF1 functions"

"number of such functions"

73

"list of unique functions and number of its occurences"

{{AppellF1[1/4, -(1/2), 1/2, 5/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))], 
  25}, {AppellF1[1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 5/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))], 
  17}, {AppellF1[5/4, 1/2, 1/2, 9/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))], 
  17}, {AppellF1[5/4, -(1/2), 3/2, 9/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))], 
  9}, {AppellF1[5/4, 1/2, 3/2, 9/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))], 
  2}, {AppellF1[9/4, 1/2, 3/2, 13/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))], 
  2}, {AppellF1[9/4, -(1/2), 5/2, 13/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))], 1}}

7

"compose Rule to make substitutions in ODE"

{AppellF1[1/4, -(1/2), 1/2, 5/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))] -> F[4, 1], 
 AppellF1[1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 5/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))] -> F[4, 2], 
 AppellF1[5/4, -(1/2), 3/2, 9/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))] -> F[4, 3], 
 AppellF1[5/4, 1/2, 1/2, 9/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))] -> F[4, 4], 
 AppellF1[5/4, 1/2, 3/2, 9/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))] -> F[4, 5], 
 AppellF1[9/4, -(1/2), 5/2, 13/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))] -> F[4, 6], 
 AppellF1[9/4, 1/2, 3/2, 13/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))] -> F[4, 7]}

"compose algebraic equations for substituted AppellF1 functions"

{F[4, 1] == 
  AppellF1[1/4, -(1/2), 1/2, 5/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))], 
 F[4, 2] == 
  AppellF1[1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 5/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))], 
 F[4, 3] == 
  AppellF1[5/4, -(1/2), 3/2, 9/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))], 
 F[4, 4] == 
  AppellF1[5/4, 1/2, 1/2, 9/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))], 
 F[4, 5] == 
  AppellF1[5/4, 1/2, 3/2, 9/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))], 
 F[4, 6] == 
  AppellF1[9/4, -(1/2), 5/2, 13/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))], 
 F[4, 7] == 
  AppellF1[9/4, 1/2, 3/2, 13/
   4, -((2 p)/(-2 p + R^2)), -((2 p)/(-2 p + bv[z]^2))]}

"modifield equation ODE of 2nd order, too long to show "
```

Finally, we solve DAE. I'm planning on doing something like

```
p0Rule2 = {p0 -> (R^2 \[Beta])/(2 (-1 + R^2 + \[Beta]))};
bvRule2 = {bv[z] -> bv[z, {q, K}], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(bv\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "n_", ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[z] -> 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(bv\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0"}], "}"}]}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[z, {q, K}]};
bv$[z_, {q_, K_}] = 1 + (-1 + K) Sin[(\[Pi] z)/2]^q;

ode2$[z_, k, \[Beta]_, R_, {q_, K_}, \[CapitalLambda]_] = 
  ode[z, k, p0, R, \[CapitalLambda]] /. p0Rule2 /. bvRule2 /. 
   bv -> bv$;
setOde$[z_, k, \[Beta]_, R_, {q_, K_}] = 
  setOde[z, k, p0, R] /. p0Rule2 /. bvRule2 /. bv -> bv$;

pf2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode2$[z, k, \[Beta], 
     Rm, {q, Km}, \[CapitalLambda]] == 0, 
   setOde$[z, k, \[Beta], Rm, {q, Km}], \[Phi][0] == 1, \[Phi]'[0] == 
    0}, {\[Phi]'[zR$], \[Phi][zR$]}, {z, 
   0, (1 + 10^-7) zR$}, {{\[Beta], 0, 1}, {\[CapitalLambda], 1, 
    1000}}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```

However, on this site I found many answers, the authors of which, on the contrary, advise converting the system of differential-algebraic equations DAE into the system of differential equations ODE. So I ask: **What are the ways to speed up the calculations in my example?**

**EDIT #1:**
It seems that `ParametricNDSolve` in contrast to `NDSolve` cannot handle DAEs. My code suggested above does not work, and careful reading of documentation confirms that it should not work.

Comment: To remember previously calculated function values you can use "memoization:": E.g.: f[x_]:= f[x] = "calculation of function value".

Comment: As usual with questions where part of the code is "too big to show", you can only get generic answers because **we cannot run your code** to troubleshoot it or improve it! You could always try to provide a smaller example that reproduces your problem though.

Comment: ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression`` should reduce the number of calls to `AppellF` to seven, if there are only seven different sets of arguments.

Comment: See also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/find-subexpression-to-minimize-leafcount-after-replacment-with-temporary-variabl/8806#8806

Comment: "It seems that `ParametricNDSolve` in contrast to `NDSolve` cannot handle DAEs." No: `psol = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t]^2 + x[t] y[t], 2 x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 == 1, 
    x[0] == a}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, a];
psol[0]`

Comment: @xzczd. Your example is not completed. Perhaps, it should be: `psol = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t]^2 + x[t] y[t], 
   2 x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 == 1, x[0] == a}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, a];
f = {x, y} /. psol;
f[0][1]`.  But this gives nothing numerical.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to modify it to `ParametricNDSolveValue`. But still, `ParametricNDSolve` can be used: `psol = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t]^2 + x[t] y[t], 2 x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 == 1, 
    x[0] == a}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, a]; {xfunc, yfunc} = {x[0], y[0]} /. psol`

Comment: Your `f` can be used, too. For example `Map[func |-> func[0][1]][f]` or `#[0][1] & /@ f`

Comment: @xzczd: `psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == y[t]^2 + x[t] y[t], 
    2 x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 == 1, x[0] == a}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, a];
psol[0][1]` yields `{InterpolatingFunction[{{0., ... "]}, {Automatic}]}[1]`, not a number,

Comment: `psol[0][1] // Through`

Comment: @xzczd: Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelE2: Please take a look at my next post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271146/how-to-use-experimentaloptimizeexpression-to-set-equation-for-parametricnds

Comment: @DanielHuber: I'm afraid memorization is not practical for my case. The test run took 43 minutes without memorization and 28 minutes with memorization , and less than 1 minute on the second run with memorization. However, the amount of memory used has been increased from 9 GB to 17 GB on a computer with 32 GB memory installed.