# Pulling out common terms when simplifying complicated equations

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I have a complicated expression where common terms are apparent but Simplify[] and FullSimplify[] don't appear able, even with plenty of assumptions added, to reduce down to a simpler form with common terms recognised so that I can give them a symbol and simplify the expressions acordingly.  A simpler example which demonstrates is

```
h (140 + Current - 
   lastU1 + (lastV1 + 
      1/2 h (140 + Current - lastU1 + (5 + 0.04 lastV1) lastV1)) (5 + 
      0.04 (lastV1 + 
         1/2 h (140 + Current - lastU1 + (5 + 0.04 lastV1) lastV1))))
```

with obvious common terms being

```
140 + Current - lastU1   -> Alpha
(5 + 0.04 lastV1) lastV1 -> Beta
```

With these and one further common term which contains them both recognised

```
(lastV1 + 1/2 h (Alpha + Beta)) -> Gamma
```

this expression can be reduced to

```
h (Alpha + Gamma (5 + 0.04` Gamma))
```

I have played with Factor[], Collect[] and many others but nothing seems to do what I need.  I am sure that Mathematica is capable of doing what I am looking for, so I am asking the experts here for tips for how best to go about it.

As a matter of interest, these expressions are going to be compiled into C eventually and I have found this to produce output of interest in terms of structuring the algebraic reduction

```
Experimental`OptimizeExpression[ expression , OptimizationLevel -> 2]
```

but I would still like more control over the manipulation before I get to this stage.

Many thanks in advance

Michael

Comment: Related: [common-subexpression-from-two-expressions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25132/common-subexpression-from-two-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

While this won't work in general with very complicated expressions (see the other post for more general approaches), you could try simple replacement rules to get a reasonable degree of simplification. If you had only linear relations, that would work for sure.
In the case of your 'toy' example

```
expr = h (140 + Current - lastU1 + (lastV1 + 1/2 h (140 + Current - 
        lastU1 + (5 + 0.04 
              lastV1) lastV1)) (5 + 0.04 (lastV1 + 1/2 h (140 +
                     Current - lastU1 + (5 + 0.04 lastV1) lastV1))))
```

the second rule below works only because it had the terms to be replaced in the very same form throughout the whole expression.

```
expr /. {lastU1 -> 140 + Current - Alpha, (5 + 0.04 lastV1) -> Beta/lastV1}
```

then you can apply the last rule

```
% /. lastV1 -> Gamma - 1/2 h (Alpha + Beta)
```

> (Alpha + (0.04 Gamma + 5) Gamma) h

Often, after applying the rules, it is a good idea to feed the resulting expression to `Simplify`.

Answer (score 1):

I am avoiding Beta and Gamma  but using symbols as the former are special symbols in Mathematica.

The rules can be applied for simplification:

```
exp = h (140 + Current - 
    lastU1 + (lastV1 + 
       1/2 h (140 + Current - 
          lastU1 + (5 + 0.04 lastV1) lastV1)) (5 + 
       0.04 (lastV1 + 
          1/2 h (140 + Current - lastU1 + (5 + 0.04 lastV1) lastV1))))
```

Then replacing all:

```
(exp //. {140 + Current - lastU1 -> \[Alpha],
    (5 + 0.04 lastV1) lastV1 -> \[Beta]}) //. (lastV1 + 
    1/2 h (\[Alpha] + \[Beta])) -> \[Gamma]
```

yields:

```
h (\[Alpha] + (5 + 0.04 \[Gamma]) \[Gamma])
```

Comment: thanks to both people, ubpdqn's was exactly the answer I am looking for

Comment: I initially had a problem with it but this is because I was using variable names already taken

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reason this does not merit a vote. Accepting both answers merely use replacement rules I point out the potential harmful unintentional use of special symbols which were actually verbatim used in other answer?

Comment: I would vote for it but I can't  :o)