# How to compile a diagonal array efficiently?

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

For example, if we use some functions defined prior to `Compile`, we usually have the main evaluators in the compiled codes, pointing to the definition of the function.

```
f[t_] := If[t <= 1., Cos[t]*Sin[t], 0.]

CompilePrint@
 Compile[{{t, _Real}}, IdentityMatrix[2] -  f[t], 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
    "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
```

> ```
>       1 argument
>       1 Integer register
>       3 Real registers
>       2 Tensor registers
>       Underflow checking off
>       Overflow checking off
>       Integer overflow checking on
>       RuntimeAttributes -> {}
>
>       R0 = A1
>       I0 = 2
>       Result = T(R2)1
>
> 1 T(I2)0 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[IdentityMatrix][ I0]]
> 2 R1 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[f][ R0]]
> 3 R2 = - R1
> 4 T(R2)1 = R2 + T(I2)0
> 5 Return
> ```

We can avoid main evaluator by using `Evaluate` in the function, which specifically substidue the definition of the function. However, sometimes this introduces repeated code in the compiled results. For instance, in the following example, `Evaluate` simplify expands a number into a matrix and repeatedly calculated this expression for two times. We can see that the 26-50 lines of the compiled code are essentially the same as 1-25 lines.

```
CompilePrint@
 Compile[{{t, _Real}}, Evaluate[IdentityMatrix[2] - f[t + 1./2.]], 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
    "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
```

> ```
>       1 argument
>       1 Boolean register
>       1 Integer register
>       12 Real registers
>       3 Tensor registers
>       Underflow checking off
>       Overflow checking off
>       Integer overflow checking on
>       RuntimeAttributes -> {}
>
>       R0 = A1
>       I0 = 1
>       R3 = 1.
>       R4 = 7.
>       R1 = 0.5
>       R7 = 0.
>       Result = T(R2)2
>
> 1 R2 = R1 + R0
> 2 B0 = R2 <= R3 (tol R4)
> 3 if[ !B0] goto 10
> 4 R2 = R1 + R0
> 5 R5 = Cos[ R2]
> 6 R6 = Sin[ R2]
> 7 R5 = R5 * R6
> 8 R6 = R5
> 9 goto 11
> 10    R6 = R7
> 11    R5 = - R6
> 12    R6 = I0
> 13    R6 = R6 + R5
> 14    R5 = R1 + R0
> 15    B0 = R5 <= R3 (tol R4)
> 16    if[ !B0] goto 23
> 17    R5 = R1 + R0
> 18    R8 = Cos[ R5]
> 19    R9 = Sin[ R5]
> 20    R8 = R8 * R9
> 21    R9 = R8
> 22    goto 24
> 23    R9 = R7
> 24    R8 = - R9
> 25    T(R1)0 ={ R6, R8 }
> 26    R6 = R1 + R0
> 27    B0 = R6 <= R3 (tol R4)
> 28    if[ !B0] goto 35
> 29    R6 = R1 + R0
> 30    R8 = Cos[ R6]
> 31    R9 = Sin[ R6]
> 32    R8 = R8 * R9
> 33    R9 = R8
> 34    goto 36
> 35    R9 = R7
> 36    R8 = - R9
> 37    R9 = R1 + R0
> 38    B0 = R9 <= R3 (tol R4)
> 39    if[ !B0] goto 46
> 40    R9 = R1 + R0
> 41    R10 = Cos[ R9]
> 42    R11 = Sin[ R9]
> 43    R10 = R10 * R11
> 44    R11 = R10
> 45    goto 47
> 46    R11 = R7
> 47    R10 = - R11
> 48    R11 = I0
> 49    R11 = R11 + R10
> 50    T(R1)1 ={ R8, R11 }
> 51    T(R2)2 ={ T(R1)0, T(R1)1 }
> 52    Return
> ```

**So is there a way to fix this repeating?**

Note that change only the argument of the external function, the behavior changes, **why**?

```
CompilePrint@
 Compile[{{t, _Real}}, Evaluate[IdentityMatrix[2] - f[t]], 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
    "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
```

> ```
>       1 argument
>       1 Boolean register
>       1 Integer register
>       6 Real registers
>       3 Tensor registers
>       Underflow checking off
>       Overflow checking off
>       Integer overflow checking on
>       RuntimeAttributes -> {}
>
>       R0 = A1
>       I0 = 1
>       R1 = 1.
>       R2 = 7.
>       R5 = 0.
>       Result = T(R2)2
>
> 1 B0 = R0 <= R1 (tol R2)
> 2 if[ !B0] goto 8
> 3 R3 = Cos[ R0]
> 4 R4 = Sin[ R0]
> 5 R3 = R3 * R4
> 6 R4 = R3
> 7 goto 9
> 8 R4 = R5
> 9 R3 = - R4
> 10    R4 = I0
> 11    R4 = R4 + R3
> 12    T(R1)0 ={ R4, R3 }
> 13    T(R1)1 ={ R3, R4 }
> 14    T(R2)2 ={ T(R1)0, T(R1)1 }
> 15    Return
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*For nicer inlining techniques, see my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54723/4330)*

In what `IdentityMatrix[2] - f[t]` evaluates to, there is pretty much four times the same code.

```
Clear[t];
IdentityMatrix[2] - f[t]
```

> {{1 - If[t <= 1., Cos[t] Sin[t], 0.], -If[t <= 1., Cos[t] Sin[t], 
>       0.]}, {-If[t <= 1., Cos[t] Sin[t], 0.], 
>     1 - If[t <= 1., Cos[t] Sin[t], 0.]}}

I will inline `f` using `DownValues`. Throughout this answer, you should read a construction like `g@@(Hold[...f[t]...]/.DownValues[f])` as `g[...f[t]...]`, only realising that now `f` has been inlined. Sadly the syntax highlighter now makes the colours of the variables a bit confusing, but what can you do.

Note that a call to `MainEvaluate` to compute a big `IdentityMatrix` is not bad. It is also not so bad to calculate `f[t]` using `MainEvaluate` only once if the matrix is very large. But I am not sure if you have large matrices in mind, or if you are interested in generating small matrices quickly (a lot of times?).

**Big matrices**

The following code makes one call to MainEvaluate to get the `IdentitiyMatrix`. It only calculates the `Sin` and the `Cos` once.

```
f[t_] := If[t <= 1., Cos[t]*Sin[t], 0.]

cfu =
 Function[Null, Compile[{{t, _Real}}, #], HoldAll] @@
  (
   Hold[
     IdentityMatrix[2] - f[t - 0.5]
     ] /. DownValues[f]
   )
```

You could also write this like this if you prefer

```
specialReleaseHold[expr_] := Delete[expr, {0, 0}]

cfu2 =
 specialReleaseHold@
  Hold[Compile][
   Unevaluated[{{t, _Real}}]
   ,
   Unevaluated @@
    (
     Hold[
       IdentityMatrix[2] - f[t - 0.5]
       ] /. DownValues[f]
     )
   ]
```

And we have

```
CompilePrint@cfu == CompilePrint@cfu2
```

> True

`ReleaseHold` would actually do the same thing as `specialReleaseHold` here (in fact, everywhere in this answer), but in similar cases using `ReleaseHold` could be bad.

Another alternative (focussed on large matrices), using `ConstantArray`

```
cfu3 =
 specialReleaseHold@
  Hold[Compile][
   Unevaluated[{{t, _Real}}],

   Unevaluated @@
     Hold[
      Block[
       {res, i},
       res =
        ConstantArray[
         -f[t - 0.5], {2, 2}
         ];
       For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++,
        res[[i, i]] += 1

        ];
       res
       ]
      ] /. DownValues[f]
   ]
```

**Small matrices**

For small matrices we want to avoid MainEvaluate altogether. We could do

```
cfu4 =
  specialReleaseHold@
   Hold[Compile][
    Unevaluated[{{t, _Real}}],
    Unevaluated @@
     (
      Hold[
        Block[{res, term},
         term = -f[t - 0.5];
         res = {{1., 0.}, {0., 1.}};
         res + term
         ]
        ] /. DownValues[f]
      )

    ];
```

Which somehow turns out to be faster than

```
cfu5 =
  specialReleaseHold@
   Hold[Compile][
    Unevaluated[{{t, _Real}}],
    Unevaluated @@
     (
      Hold[
        Block[{term},
         term = -f[t - 0.5];
         {{1. + term, 0. + term}, {0. + term, 1. + term}}
         ]
        ] /. DownValues[f]
      )
    ];
```

As we will see further below, neither of these functions use `MainEvaluate`.

**Uncompiled (small matrices)**

We will see indeed that compiling pays off. For reference, we define the following function

```
fu =
  ReleaseHold@
   Hold[Function][
    Hold[t],
    Hold[
      Block[{term},
       term = -f[t - 0.5];
       {{1. + term, 0. + term}, {0. + term, 1. + term}}
       ]
      ] /. DownValues[f]
    ];
```

**Comparison**

```
cfu[2.] == cfu2[2.] == cfu3[2.] == cfu4[2.] == cfu5[2.] == fu[2.]==
 IdentityMatrix[2]
```

> True

```
cfu[0.1] == cfu2[0.1] == cfu3[0.1] == cfu4[0.1] == cfu5[0.1] == fu[0.1]
```

> True

```
StringFreeQ[CompilePrint@#, "MainEvaluate"] & /@
 {cfu, cfu2, cfu3, 
  cfu4, cfu5}
```

{False, False, False, True, True}

```
Function[Do[#[0.1], {10000}] // Timing // First] /@ {cfu, cfu2, cfu3, 
  cfu4, cfu5, fu}
```

> {0.023010, 0.020006, 0.024175, 0.009206, 0.011438, 0.077503}

Comment: Actually the who term thing isn't necessary. That is what I would do in C, but that's irrelevant. So you can get rid of the Block as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "the term thing isn't necessary"?

Comment: Actually it seems to have the same behavior(problem) as in the question: if you use `f[t+0.5]` instead of `f[t]`, you get duplicated code in the compiled result.

Comment: @xslittlegrass thanks for the reply, I will see whats wrong

Comment: @xslittlegrass I think I know what the problem is. The function I used did not have a Hold attribute, so things got evaluated.

Comment: @xslittlegrass I have edited the answer

Comment: Does this means that explicitly inline the identity matrix is the fastest way? What if my f uses some global variables, for example, `a=1.; f[t_] := If[t <= a, a*Cos[t]*Sin[t], 0.]`?

Comment: @xslittlegrass I am still unsure if you mean to use the code for large matrices or for the small 2x2 matrix. For small matrices, inlining the matrix is fastest, otherwise not. If f depends on a global variable, I would probably still inline f and make the global variable an argument of the compiled function.

Comment: Also thank you for the accept, I hope it helps!

Comment: Let me know if you have more questions. The technique using DownValues can be made much more readable by the way, maybe I should edit.

Answer (score 4):

This answer deals only with `f`, not `IdentityMatrix` (which is sadly not compilable).

`Compile` is much better at extracting expressions form pure functions.  If you are going to use InlineExternalDefinitions, consider making the external functions pure `Function`s.

```
In[10]:= Clear[f]

f = Function[t, If[t <= 1., Cos[t]*Sin[t], 0.]];

CompilePrint@
 Compile[{{t, _Real}}, IdentityMatrix[2] - f[t], 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
    "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]

Out[12]= "
        1 argument
        1 Boolean register
        1 Integer register
        7 Real registers
        2 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        R0 = A1
        R2 = 1.
        R3 = 7.
        I0 = 2
        R6 = 0.
        Result = T(R2)1

1   T(I2)0 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[IdentityMatrix][ I0]]
2   R1 = R0
3   B0 = R1 <= R2 (tol R3)
4   if[ !B0] goto 10
5   R4 = Cos[ R1]
6   R5 = Sin[ R1]
7   R4 = R4 * R5
8   R5 = R4
9   goto 11
10  R5 = R6
11  R1 = - R5
12  T(R2)1 = R1 + T(I2)0
13  Return
"
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the compiled function shares (as in shares the memory) the tensor that is produced by `IdentityMatrix` with the kernel. Would you not agree that there is little overhead in one call to `MainEvaluate` and that any compiled version of this would be hardly any faster?

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I really don't know.  If it's a constant matrix, like here, and not generated by the compiled function, I'd just embed it.

Comment: I think the memory is shared because of experiments I have done using `MaxMemoryUsed`, especially in cases where I "initialised" a large array using `ConstantArray`. But I may be wrong :). I agree about embedding the matrix. I may have jumped to the conclusion that the purpose was really to do this for larger matrices. If that is not the case, the overhead of one call to `MainEvaluate` may be significant. Oh well :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Sorry, I wasn't clear in my comment.  I am sure that the memory is shared.  It's even shared in LibraryLink functions and I assume MVM compiled functions have a tighter integration into the kernel.  What I meant by "I really don't know" is that I'm not sure how much the MainEvaluate overhead is.  I've never measured.

Comment: Looking at the bytecode, `IdentityMatrix` is called using opcode 47. So, the overhead of this call should really be very small, as it doesn't actually invoke the full evaluator, but rather jumps straight to the entry point of the `IdentityMatrix` function.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, that's very helpful. Do you know how to deal with it if f uses some global variables? For example `a = 1.;
f = Function[t, If[t <= a, a*Cos[t]*Sin[t], 0.]];`

Comment: @OleksandrR. Interesting, what does opcode mean and how can I look at opcode?

Comment: @xslittlegrass opcode is short for "operation code" and refers to a (numbered) VM instruction. Look at the `InputForm` of the compiled function to see them.

Answer (score 4):

The reason about *change only the argument of the external function, the behavior changes* may be related to the setting of [`"ExpressionOptimization"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompilationOptions.html) under `CompilationOptions`.

There is a related function called `OptimizeExpression` under `` Experimental` `` context, which <strike>I believe</strike>, according to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25136/17) by [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau), is the one used by `Compile` for expression optimization.

`OptimizeExpression` can detect some common expressions in code:

```
Needs["Experimental`"]

OptimizeExpression[  IdentityMatrix[2] - f[t]  ]
```

> ```
> OptimizedExpression[
>     Block[{Compile`$8, Compile`$9}, 
>       Compile`$8 = -If[t <= 1., Cos[t] Sin[t], 0.]; 
>           Compile`$9 = 1 + Compile`$8;
>       {{Compile`$9, Compile`$8}, {Compile`$8, Compile`$9}}
>          ]]
> ```

But somehow it fails to detect the common expression in `IdentityMatrix[2] - f[t + 1./2.]`:

```
OptimizeExpression[   IdentityMatrix[2] - f[t + 1./2.]   ]
```

> ```
> OptimizedExpression[
>   Block[{Compile`$5, Compile`$13, Compile`$18, Compile`$23},
>   {{1 - If[0.5` + t <= 1.`, Compile`$5 = 0.5` + t; Cos[Compile`$5] Sin[Compile`$5], 0.`],
> ```
>
> -If[0.5`+ t <= 1.`, Compile`$13 = 0.5` + t; Cos[Compile`$13] Sin[Compile`$13], 0.`]},
>    {-If[0.5` + t <= 1.`, Compile`$18 = 0.5` + t; Cos[Compile`$18] Sin[Compile`$18], 0.`],
>   1 - If[0.5` + t <= 1.`, Compile`$23 = 0.5` + t; Cos[Compile`$23] Sin[Compile`$23], 0.`]
>           }}
>              ]]

One of the possible (and hopefully temporary) solution would be substituting definition of `f` **after** the `OptimizeExpression` being applied:

```
compfunc = Compile[{{t, _Real}},
        Evaluate[
            OptimizeExpression[
                    Hold[
                                IdentityMatrix[2] - f[t + 1./2.]
                                ] /. f -> fTemp // ReleaseHold
                    ] /. fTemp[x_] :> With[{val = f[x]}, val /; True]
            ]
        ]

Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
compfunc // CompilePrint
```

> ```
>  "(*omitted*)
>
>  1    R2 = R1 + R0
>  2    B0 = R2 <= R3 (tol R4)
>  3    if[ !B0] goto 9
>  4    R5 = Cos[ R2]
>  5    R6 = Sin[ R2]
>  6    R5 = R5 * R6
>  7    R6 = R5
>  8    goto 10
>  9    R6 = R7
>  10   R5 = - R6
>  11   R8 = I0
>  12   R8 = R8 + R5
>  13   T(R1)0 ={ R8, R5 }
>  14   T(R1)1 ={ R5, R8 }
>  15   T(R2)2 ={ T(R1)0, T(R1)1 }
>  16   Return
>  "
> ```

Comment: @xslittlegrass You're welcome :) Still I don't know why `OptimizeExpression` failed in the second example...