# What can be inlined by "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True?

Tags: compile, implementation-details, undocumented

This not-well-documented option of `Compile` has [been used quite a bit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%22InlineExternalDefinitions%22) in this site, and based on these examples, I used to think `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True` only works for

1. Compilable numbers
2. Compilable pure functions
3. Compiled functions

until the day I was astonished by [*George Varnavides: “Symmetry in Chaos” (128 characters)*](http://blog.wolfram.com/2016/11/09/the-2016-wolfram-one-liner-competition-winners/). In this example, a non-numeric **`Symbol`** is inlined! The relevant part can be boiled down to the following example:

```
a = #;
cf = Compile[{c}, Nest[a &, c, 10],
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];

<<"CompiledFunctionTools`"
CompilePrint@cf
```

So my question is,

1. Is this example just a special case, or it represents a family of expressions that can be inlined by `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True`?
2. Is there other type(s) of inlineable expressions? Has anyone already summarized it?

P.S. George's code piece is quite tricky, if you have trouble in understanding it, consider posting a new question like "why does George's code work?".

Comment: From my experience what are usually inlined are other compiled functions. Their code is copied into the main function everytime they are called by the main function.

Comment: @faysou Yeah as mentioned in the question that's one type of inlineable expressions I was aware of. What I'm interested is, 1. Are there more? 2. Is there a simple rule for judging whether a expression can be inlined or not?

Comment: `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True` is very similar to using `With`. For example `f1 = Sin[x^2];
cf1 = Compile[ {{x}}, f1, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
CompilePrint[ cf1]` (a case not covered by your list) is like using `With[{f2 = Sin[x^2]},
 cf2 = Compile[ {{x}}, f2, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> False}];
 CompilePrint[ cf2]
 ]`. There might be special cases (recursion?) were this analogy fails.

Comment: @Karsten7. 1. The first example you gave is surprising! (BTW, though not related to the topic, another surprising thing is, `With[{mid = Sin[x^2]}, Compile[{x}(*notice the seemingly trivial modification here*), mid]] // CompilePrint` isn't compiled. ) 2. I think `"InlineExternalDefinitions"->True` isn't that similar to `Evaluate` or `HoldAll`, because e.g. `f1 = Sin[x^2]; cf = 
 Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, First[f1], 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]; CompilePrint[cf]` can't be implemented with these technique.

Comment: @Karsten7. Just noticed halirutan has told me this before but I forgot about it, Oh…: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35824353#35824353

Comment: Btw, the behavior of `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True` even [changed between v9 and v10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54694/18476).

Comment: @Karsten7. I think you can summarize your comments to an answer, it does (at least partly) answer my question.

Answer (score 6):

In general, investigating this features is mostly trial and error, because [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) is a pure kernel function that resists inspection by `PrintDefinitions` or `Trace`. Therefore, the only reliable source of information are the one example from the documentation and trying things out. What follows is list of rules extended from my comments.

### What can be inlined by `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True`?

In principle, basic *own values* (see [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues.html)) created using [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) can potentially be inlined by `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True`.

```
ext1 = 1;
ext2 = Pi;
ext3 = #;
ext4 = Sin[x];
ext5 = Compile[{x}, Cos[x]];
ext6 = #^2 &;

cf = Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}},
  ext1*ext2 + Nest[ext3 &, x, 10] + ext6[ext4*ext5[x]]
  , CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
  ]

Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
CompilePrint@cf
```

Also the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) of indexed objects (the `DownValues` with a single match) can become inlined.

```
extDV1[1] := 1;
extDV2[1] = 1;
extDV3[y] = x;

cf2 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}}, extDV1[1] + extDV2[1] + extDV3[y], 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
CompilePrint@cf2
```

### What can't be inlined by `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True`?

Everything else, especially `OwnValues` created by `SetDelayed` and [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) that rely on pattern matching, can't be inlined by `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True`.

```
ext7 := 1;
cf3 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}},
  ext7*x
  , CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
  ]

CompilePrint@cf3


ext8[x_] := x;
cf4 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}},
  ext8[x]
  , CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
  ]

CompilePrint@cf4
```

### What will be inlined?

Which `DownValues` will be inlined by `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True` is decided by the algorithm of `Compile` and is therefore hard to predict. It has even [changed between version 9 and 10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54694/in-compile-inlineexternaldefinitions-doesnt-work-anymore-in-mma-v10-like-in-v).

Wolfram Technical Support: "According to the developers, nPara is not inlined because Mathematica is making the conservative assumption that nPara might change in the future."

### How to force inlining?

Comment: I donated a small introduction and as you have already commented on the issue, I really appreciate that you stepped up and wrote an answer. +1

Comment: @halirutan Thank you, I appreciate it. I was hoping someone would provide a more profound answer. My comments mainly expressed my own confusion and were intended to add some more aspects to the question.

Comment: I'll add some more content to the last two sections later.

Comment: Here comes a strange (and buggy?) exception of `SetDelayed`…: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/158186/1871

Answer (score 1):

Here is another contribution to the deciphering of `"InlineExternalDefinitions"->True` through trial and error. It may inline the first instance of  a symbol but fail to do so for the second, as in the following example:

```
ClearAll[a, cf];
a = Range[3];
cf = Compile[{{var, _Real}},
   var^a + var^a,
   {{a, _Integer, 1}},
   CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
CompilePrint@cf
```

[image]

`a` clearly was inlined into T(I1)0, and used in line 1 of the printout, but was then obtained by a call to `MainEvaluate` to be used in the second term.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the issue shown above was the result of a bug that has been fixed in the version under development.

Comment: In _v8.0.4_ and _v9.0.1_ `a` is correctly inlined. Which version are you in?

Comment: @xzcxd The bug in question was introduced somewhere in the version 10 cycle.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for the info. Good to know it has been addressed.

Comment: @xzczd I'm using "11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 27, 2017)"