# Strange behavior of Table

Tags: bugs, list-manipulation, compile

Whenever I run the code

```
a = 0;
code := (a++);
Table[code; a, {1000}]
```

I get a list of 1000 zeros. However, if I replace 1000 with 100, then a get a list equal to Range[100]. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: I get the same behavior (Mac OS X, MMA 11.2).  The phenomenon seems to switch at 249/250.

Comment: I get: `n <= 249` gives `Range[249]`. `n > 250` gives 250 zeros. (Win10, MMA 11.2)

Comment: I get the same behavior with versions 5.2 and 8.0.4 on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 32):

This is because `Table` automatically compiles its argument above a certain length limit.

```
SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "TableCompileLength"]
(* {"CompileOptions" -> {"TableCompileLength" -> 250}} *)
```

It does not seem to realize that the code modifies global variables because that behaviour is hidden behind `code`. Notice that the following both work fine:

```
Table[a++; a, {1000}]
```

```
Clear[code]
a = 0;
code[] := (a++);
Table[code[]; a, {1000}]
```

I would call this behaviour "a bug", but at the same time I would advise to try to stick to conventions.  Do not define a symbol in such a way that its evaluation has side effects, at least not without good reason. This is not only confusing to the auto-compiler, it is also confusing to people who read your code.

Comment: Really helpful explanation!  So ... shd this question get a `bug` tag?