# Functions within modules within Compile

Tags: functions, scoping, compile

I've noticed that if I try to define a `Function` within a `Module` within `Compile`, I get errors of `(* Compiled expression Function[...] should be a machine-size real number *)` **IF** those functions are local variables within the `Module` **AND** I don't assign the `Module` itself to a variable name within `Compile`.  Weird, no?  I know about using the trailing `..., {{Pattern, _Type}}` syntax, but I don't think that's applicable here (besides, I'm not sure that a type of `Function` is listed in the supported types, anyways... -- yet it does appear that they can be used within `Compile`).

I'm still too new to `Compile` to know whether putting the `Function`s within a `Module` is even advised, but I read elsewhere that using symbols that aren't shielded within something like a `Module` causes calls to `MainEvaluate[]`, which considerably slows performance.

Any idea why this happens?

````
Compile[{},
  f1 = Function[{}, 1.0]; (* Fine! *)
  f2 = 1.0 &; (* Fine! *)
  
  Module[{f3, f4},
   (*f3=Function[{},1.0];*)
   (* ABOVE: Compiled expression Function[{}, 1.`] should be a machine-size real number *)
   (*f4=1.0&;*) (* Same *)
   f5 = Function[{}, 1.0]; (* Fine! *)
   f6 = 1.0 &; (* Fine! *)
   {f5[], f6[]}
   ];
  mod = Module[{f7, f8},
    f7 = Function[{}, 1.0]; (* Fine! *)
    f8 = 1.0 &; (* Fine! *)
    {f7[], f8[]}
    ];
  mod
  ][]
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case using `With` is enough:

```
With[{f3 = Function[y, y^4], f1 = Function[y, y^2]},
c1 = Compile[{x},
       f1[x];
       {Function[y, y^3][x], f3[x]}   
     ]
];
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
compiledOKQ = StringFreeQ[CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[#1], "MainEvaluate"]&;
compiledOKQ[c1]
```

gives `True`

Answer (score 3):

I think I answered my own question via `CompilePrint` (just learned about this); will post for posterity:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8]
f3 := Function[y, y^4];
c1 = Compile[{x},
   m1 = Module[{f1},
     f1 = Function[y, y^2];
     f1[x]
     ];
   Module[{},
    {Function[y, y^3][x], f3[x]}
    ]
   ];
c1[2]
m1
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[c1]
```

```
1   V17 = MainEvaluate[                                                 \
  2
Function[{x}, m1 = Module[{f1}, f1 = Function[y, y ]; f1[x]]][ R0]]
2   R2 = R0
3   R1 = Power[ R2, I0]
4   R2 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[f3][ R0]]
5   T(R1)0 = {R1, R2}
6   Return
```

It looks like the versions that I thought were "working" were just running in non-compiled mode (not just the assignments, either -- the whole step).  I'm used to getting an error/warning in such cases, but I had to look at `CompilePrint` to see it this time.

I guess you just have to use anonymous functions exclusively.  It looks like BOTH the methods in my original post AND defining the `Function` outside of `Compile` altogether (as I indicated I was unsure-about in my original post) cause `MainEvaluate[]` to be used...

I could've sworn I'd come across other examples on StackOverflow where a function was defined outside of `Compile` and then used within it, but I'll have to educate myself further.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145991/what-can-be-inlined-by-inlineexternaldefinitions-true