# Using Compile with vector expressions

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, compile

Consider a vector

```
vec[x_,y_,z_]={x^0.5*y^0.1,y^0.3*z^0.1,z^2*x*y};
```

I need to calculate, say, a table with vector values for the coordinates

```
tabscord=RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^7, 3}];
```

I would like to use Compile. This is my realization:

```
tabcompiled = 
 Hold@Compile[{{tabscord, _Real, 2}}, 
   Table[vec[tabscord[[i]][[1]], tabscord[[i]][[2]], 
     tabscord[[i]][[3]]], {i, 1, Length[tabscord], 1}], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
  DownValues@vec//ReleaseHold
```

However, it says

> CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression
> {0.815274,0.188035,0.433407} should be a machine-size real number.

To avoid this problem, I need to define first the coordinates of the vector, say,

```
vecx[x_,y_,z_]=vec[x,y,z][[1]];
vecy[x_,y_,z_]=vec[x,y,z][[2]];
vecz[x_,y_,z_]=vec[x,y,z][[3]];

And then

tabcompiled = 
 Hold@Compile[{{tabscord, _Real, 2}}, 
   Table[{vecx[tabscord[[i]][[1]], tabscord[[i]][[2]], 
     tabscord[[i]][[3]]],vecy[tabscord[[i]][[1]], tabscord[[i]][[2]], 
     tabscord[[i]][[3]]],vecz[tabscord[[i]][[1]], tabscord[[i]][[2]], 
     tabscord[[i]][[3]]]}, {i, 1, Length[tabscord], 1}], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
  DownValues@vecx/.DownValues@vecy/.DownValues@vecz//ReleaseHold
```

Could you please tell me whether it is possible to avoid defining separate coordinates of `vec` if using Compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a pure function

```
vec = Function[{x,y,z},{x^0.5*y^0.1,y^0.3*z^0.1,z^2*x*y}];
```

and inlining works:

```
f = Compile[{{x,_Real,2}},
      Table[vec[x[[i,1]],x[[i,2]],x[[i,3]]],{i,1,Length[tabscord]}],
      CompilationTarget->"C",RuntimeOptions->"Speed",
      CompilationOptions->{"InlineExternalDefinitions"->True}
];

tabscord=RandomReal[{0,1},{10^7,3}];
f[tabscord]
(* takes about 3 seconds *)
```

See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148189/85954) for inlining definitions.

Answer (score 5):

I understand that the question is about `Compile`, but this is a case where it is easy to get fast code without compiling: Assuming OP's definitions

```
vec[x_,y_,z_]={x^0.5*y^0.1,y^0.3*z^0.1,z^2*x*y};
tabscord=RandomReal[{0,1},{10^7,3}];
```

one can use

```
Transpose[vec@@Transpose[tabscord]]
(* takes about 1.3 seconds *)
```

**Comments:**

- The inner transpose turns the three big columns into three big rows, and `vec@@` then means that `vec` is called with `x` equal to the entire first column of `tabscord`, `y` equal to the second column, `z` the third column.
- Therefore, `z^2*x*y` is called with `x`, `y`, `z` equal to vectors of length $10^7$ which we can be sure is already optimized and we do not have to compile.
- Always make sure that arrays are packed. Here they are.

Comment: Thanks! However, my question just illustrates the basic problem I deal with every time when considering vector definitions.