# Is it possible to speedup these simple linear algebra operations

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I'm trying to numerically solve some equations using splitting operator method. The solver I construct iteratively constructs a matrix and feeds it to `LinearSolve`. After profiling with the solver, I found half of the time is spent on simple linear algebra operations before `LinearSolve`, and I would like to speedup these process if possible.

Consider this simple example of matrix operation

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
Needs["Experimental`"]

lth = 200;
mtx = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {lth, lth}];
ls = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {lth}];

Et = Function[{t}, Sin[(π t)/20] Sin[2 t]];
```

and I'm trying to construct a matrix `IdentityMatrix[lth] + I (DiagonalMatrix[ls] + Et[t]*mtx)`, repeatly with different `t`:

```
Table[
       IdentityMatrix[lth] + I (DiagonalMatrix[ls] + Et[t]*mtx);, {t, 0., 
        20, 0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.33086, Null} *)
```

As a comparison, `LinearSolve` is about 2X faster for solving a matrix equation with the same size

```
Table[
   LinearSolve[mtx, ls];, {t, 0., 20, 0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.883315, Null} *)
```

So my goal is to speed up the matrix operation, especially considering my matrix operation is much simpler than what is required to solve a dense matrix equation in `LinearSolve`.

We can try to copmile the functions:

```
Etc = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, Et[t], 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
Htc = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, 
  IdentityMatrix[lth] + I (DiagonalMatrix[ls] + Et[t]*mtx), 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
    "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
```

and compare these different ways:

```
Table[
   IdentityMatrix[lth] + I (DiagonalMatrix[ls] + Et[t]*mtx);, {t, 0., 
    20, 0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[IdentityMatrix[lth] + I (DiagonalMatrix[ls] + Etc[t]*mtx);, {t, 
    0., 20, 0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[Htc[t];, {t, 0., 20, 0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.33086, Null} *)
(* {1.29705, Null} *)
(* {2.26304, Null} *)
```

We have two observations:

1. We gain only very little speedup in by compiling the function `Et`.
2. We slow down almost 70% by compiling the whole matrix operations.

For the first point, I'm guessing this may due to the automatic compilation of `Table`.
For the second point, we may look at the compiled code of the function `Htc`

```
"(*omitted*)
1   T(I2)0 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[IdentityMatrix][ I0]]
2   T(R2)2 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[DiagonalMatrix][ T(R1)1]]
3   R1 = R0
4   R5 = I1
5   R3 = Reciprocal[ R5]
6   R5 = R2 * R1 * R3
7   R3 = Sin[ R5]
8   R5 = I2
9   R5 = R5 * R1
10  R6 = Sin[ R5]
11  R3 = R3 * R6
12  T(R2)4 = R3 * T(R2)3
13  T(R2)2 = T(R2)2 + T(R2)4
14  T(C2)4 = C0 * T(R2)2
15  T(C2)2 = CoerceTensor[ I3, T(I2)0]]
16  T(C2)2 = T(C2)2 + T(C2)4
17  Return
"
```

We can see that it has two invokes to the `MainEvaluate` to compute the `IdentityMatrix` and `DiagonalMatrix`. So this slowdown may come from the repeatedly invoking of the MainEvaluator, although in the comment [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38918/1364) Oleksandr R. pointed out that `IdentityMatrix` is called using opcode 47 which should give very small overhead.

We can try to remove the `MainEvaluate` completely by expanding the matrix using [Silvia's construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45257/1364) (this construction is a workaround for a problem of `OptimizedExpression`):

```
Htc2 = 
  Compile[{{t, _Real}}, 
   Evaluate[
    OptimizeExpression[
      Hold[IdentityMatrix[lth] + 
          I (DiagonalMatrix[ls] + Et[t]*mtx)] /. Et -> EtTemp // 
       ReleaseHold] /. 
     EtTemp[x_] :> With[{val = Et[x]}, val /; True]]];

Table[Htc2[t];, {t, 0., 20, 0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {5.30743, Null} *)
```

However, we see an almost 2X slowdown for some reasons.

We can also try to simplify the matrix operations manually by removing `IdentityMatrix`, and it gains almost 2X speedup

```
Table[ 
   DiagonalMatrix[1. + I ls] + I Etc[t]*mtx;, {t, 0., 20, 
    0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.728859, Null} *)
```

But I'm sill wondering:

**Is it possible to further speedup the matrix operations?**

---

version: 10.4 on OS X 10.11.4.

Note: This is a follow-up question to the question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38904/1364).