# Extract repeated patterns without user intervention

Tags: mathematical-optimization

If I copy-paste HUGE analytical mathematical formulas from Mathematica to C++ (huge means > 800 chars), is there a way to extract repeated patterns? Because I don't want to recalculate the same thing many times in C++.

What I mean is this. Following code extracted from Mathematica:

```
N = (a * x + b) * sqrt(a * a + b * b) + (a * x + b);
My = x * x * (a * x + b) * sqrt(a * a + b * b) + (a * x + b) * y;
```

Become automatically (with a Mathematica magic way) like:

```
axb = a * x + b;
sqr = sqrt(a * a + b * b);
xx = x * x;
N = axb * (sqr + 1);
My = (xx * sqr + y) * axb;
```

Is this possible automatically?
If not, is it possible, if I inspect repeated patterns in super HUGE formulas?

Comment: Try ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression[(x + y)^2 + (x + y)^3]``, although Mathematica will decide how to abbreviate things.  And also, don't set anything equal to `N` because `N` is a built-in function.  Observe: `N[4/3]`.

Comment: Have a look also at [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2878/problem-with-compile-function/2885)

Comment: It may be the case that the C++ compiler itself can reduce recalculations if optimization is set to a high level. Have you tried this already?

Comment: I am not totally sure, but I believe C++ compilers do not optimize floating points because their representation can vary from architecture to architecture. Even if they are integers on mathematical formula, I trust more the Mathematica optimization from a C++ compiler.

Comment: Chameleon, I believe Somos is referring to the built-in C compiler that you can use Mathematica. Please clarify, have you tried this?